# UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'key' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

here is my code i am facing this error i am  not able to find the error fix the error shoow

```
def get_key(res_by):
    if res_by == '#1':
        key = 'transaction_id'
    elif res_by == '#2':
        key = 'created'
    return key
def get_chart(chart_type, data, results_by, **kwargs):
        plt.switch_backend('AGG')
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
        key = get_key(results_by)
```

thats the code

Comment: What if `res_by` isn't #1 or #2?

Comment: Both conditions didn't match, `key` is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if `res_by` is not `#1 or #2`? It wont be defined. Try this.

```
def get_key(res_by):
    if res_by == '#1':
        key = 'transaction_id'
    elif res_by == '#2':
        key = 'created'
    else:
        key = None
    return key
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in case *both* conditions fail, `key` is not assigned any value, but you return `key`. You thus need to specify a value in the `else` case:

```
def get_key(res_by):
    if res_by == '#1':
        key = 'transaction_id'
    elif res_by == '#2':
        key = 'created'
    else:
        key = something  # ← specify a value if the two conditions fail
    return key
```